# How to decently destroy opengl resources when using QOpenGLWidget in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyopengl, qtopengl

First of all, My codes are as follows:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QOpenGLWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QOpenGLShader, QOpenGLShaderProgram, QMatrix4x4, QOpenGLBuffer, QOpenGLVertexArrayObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

import numpy as np
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import sys

class OpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.frame_count = 0

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.program = QOpenGLShaderProgram()
        self.program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader.Vertex, """
            attribute highp vec4 aPos;
            void main() {
                gl_Position = aPos;
            }
        """)
        self.program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader.Fragment, """
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        """)

        self.program.link()
        self.program.bind()

        self.vertices = np.array([
            [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
            [0.0, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
            [-0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
            [-0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
            [0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0],
        ], dtype=np.float32)

        self.indices = np.array([
            0,1,2,2,3,4
        ], dtype=np.uint16)
        
        self.vao = QOpenGLVertexArrayObject()
        self.vbo = QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer.VertexBuffer)
        self.ibo = QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer.IndexBuffer)
        self.vao.create()
        self.vbo.create()
        self.ibo.create()
        self.vao.bind()        
        self.vbo.bind()
        self.ibo.bind()
        self.vbo.allocate(self.vertices.nbytes)
        self.ibo.allocate(self.indices.nbytes)
        self.vbo.write(0, self.vertices.tobytes(), self.vertices.nbytes)        
        self.ibo.write(0, self.indices.tobytes(), self.indices.nbytes)
        posAttribLoc = self.program.attributeLocation("aPos")
        self.program.setAttributeBuffer(posAttribLoc, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, 4, 0)
        self.program.enableAttributeArray(posAttribLoc) 
        self.vbo.release()
        self.vao.release()
    
    def paintGL(self):
        gl = self.context().versionFunctions() 
        gl.glClearColor(0.33,0.33,0.33, 1.0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.vao.bind()
        self.program.bind()

        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, len(self.indices), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
        self.frame_count += 1
    
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    
    def __del__(self):
        self.vao.destroy()
        self.vbo.destroy()
        self.ibo.destroy()        
        self.program.removeAllShaders()
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = OpenGLWidget()
    window = QMainWindow()    
    window.setCentralWidget(widget)
    window.setGeometry(0,0,640,480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Everything goes well, I can render it as expected. But python complains:

```
in __del__
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QOpenGLVertexArrayObject has been deleted
```

when I close the window. Guess the buffer is freed twice so I change the destructor to

```
    def __del__(self):
        pass
```

while the interpreter complain

```
QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::destroy() failed to restore current context
```

After closing. I think there must be something wrong on freeing, can anyone figure out proper way to release these buffers?

**UPDAETE**
Enlightened by [*Resource Initialization and Cleanup* topic within Qt doc](https://devdocs.io/qt%7E5.12/qopenglwidget), we can connect `aboutToBeDestroyed` signal to a customized slot function for cleanup:

```
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.glContext = None

    def paintGL(self):
        if self.glContext is None: 
            self.glContext = self.context()
            self.glContext.aboutToBeDestroyed.connect(self.cleanup)

        gl = self.glContext.versionFunctions() 
        gl.glClearColor(0.33,0.33,0.33, 1.0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.vao.bind()
        self.program.bind()

        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, len(self.indices), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
        self.frame_count += 1

    def cleanup(self):
        print('cleanup called')
        self.makeCurrent()
        self.vao.destroy()
        self.vbo.destroy()
        self.ibo.destroy()        
        self.program.removeAllShaders()
        self.doneCurrent()
```

However, `cleanup` still not called after closing window

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run cleanup methods when a window is closed, I would recommend overloading the widget's `closeEvent` like so:

```py
class OpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent) -> None:
        # Call cleanup methods here
        return super().closeEvent(event)
```

This way you should be able to guarantee that the cleanup methods are called before the widget and any processes that it is running are destroyed.

Comment: closeEvent not called when closing windows in my case

Comment: @Finley In that case could you provide some additional information on how you're closing the window?

Comment: By clicking the x button on top bar

Comment: I may have misunderstood something, is the QOpenGLWidget itself a window or is it inside a window? If it is not a window itself, then you need to overload the closeEvent of the window containing the QOpenGLWidget.

Comment: I have tried overloading `closeEvent`, not work for me.